# Prevent other users from calling php file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Here I have a PHP code:

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php
  $pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=gmaestro_agro;host=localhost","gmaestro_agro","pass");
  $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM stat");
  $statement->execute();
  $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json=json_encode($results);
  echo $json;
?>
```

I call this code with Ajax to get data from MySql database, but when some go on domain `http://mywebsite.com/get_json.php` this code give anyone information of my database. How I can prevent other users from calling this, so only with my JS Ajax code can call it?

Comment: Your original question was about an `INSERT` using `mysql_*`. Your update has a `SELECT` using PDO. You should decide what you want to ask, this is just wasting everybody's time.

Comment: sorry...... i just want to prevent from calling php files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least you should check whether a `POST` request was made:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  // your code
}
```

That way you will not fill your database with empty entries every time that page is requested via `GET`.

Your code also allows for anonymous posts. It is possible that it is designed that way, but if not, you should check for a logged-in user. Normally you use [sessions](http://www.php.net/session_start) for that.

Apart from that you should validate the individual fields, some might be empty but others probably have to be filled before you do your insert.

**Edit:** You can also set a session variable in the "main" page and check for that variable in the ajax script. That way the visitor would have to visit the main page at least once but after that, the ajax script could be requested without any problems.

Comment: I update my question, please see it, Do stuff change when I use PDO?

Answer (score 1):

There is no completely reliable way to get sure, the script is called via AJAX. Things you can do:

1. Do a proper validation (to prevent the creation of empty rows)
2. You can check the `HTTP_REFERRER`, (be aware: this value can be faked)
3. You can use

   isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'

but of course, also this can be faked

Comment: You can also obfuscate the Javascript code, so it will make it harder for somebody to reverse engineer it.

Comment: I update my question, please see it, Do stuff change when I use PDO?

Comment: There is no need for reverse engineer anything, you can e.g. simplify look into the network tab of Firebug to see the requests sent to the server. So it's not worth the effort to obfuscate something for this particular reason

Comment: Hmm, you say "so how I can prevent this from calling from users, so how to call this only with my JS AJAX code ?" -> if only authorized persons should see this data, you have to check, whether the user has the permissions to get the JSON data within you script - or do I overlook something obvious? A check whether called via AJAX or not is in my opinion not really necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Send an additional information in POST, let's say `$_POST['From_ajax']` and then check in your PHP program if that information was set - if not, do nothing, otherwise execute the databse commands.

EDIT: Of course anyone will be able to work out how this works if they try and will be able to call your script if they want, this only prevents executing the script accidentally by random users who open it. If you really want noone else but you to be able to call your script I guess you might need some kind of electronic signature.

Comment: I update my questin, so please look it,